# Tastypie queries for all fields, is it possible to only SELECT specific fields

Tags: django, tastypie

With tastypie you create a resource for your Django model and point the `queryset` at your `model.objects.all()`.
I was expecting "fields"  to allow me to declare which fields i want to return: https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resources.html?highlight=exclude#fields

This does work, but the sql query generated doesnt care it selects all fields. For me this seems a bit bit pointless if im querying a large table and only want to return 2 columns, and not the other 8.

Hopefully I've missed something obvious in the TP documentation.
If anyone has any pointers/ideas that would be great